# How do I change class <type> to Python type <list>

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, class

I'm new to OOP so this maybe is an anti-pattern but, I have a class:

```py
class SomeObject:

    """  WIP OBJECT  """

    parsed_dates = []

    def __init__(self, description, weekdays, months):
        self.description = str(description)
        self.weekdays = frozenset(SomeObject.flatn(weekdays))  # flat set of ints
        self.months = frozenset(SomeObject.flatn(months))  # flat set of ints


    def __repr__(self):
        return self.description

   ( ... ) 

    def accepts(self, dt):
        return any([
            dt.weekday() in self.weekdays,
            dt.month in self.months,
     ])
```

And I build a defaultdict with:

```py
def main(dt_start, dt_end, s: str):
    d = defaultdict(list)
    description = pull_desc(s=s)
    active_days = convert_tuples_to_numpy_array(description, np.str)
    SomeObject.active_days(active_days_for_meter)
    for test_set in SomeObject.parsed_dates:
        for dt in [dt for dt in SomeObject.date_range(dt_start, dt_end) if test_set.accepts(dt)]:
            # add the datetime objects to a list of values with the description as the key
            d[test_set].append(str(dt.isoformat()))
    return d
```

Which returns:

`defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {['Saturdays']: ['2020-01-04', '2020-01-11', '2020-01-18']}`

Now when I go to compare the key (resembles a list) of this defaultdict() to say , Python doesn't recognize the key as its of type `'__main__.SomeObject'>` rather than type `list`

i.e:

`dic = {"Saturday": 1}`

```py
for k1, v2 in dic.items()
  for k2, v2 in defaultdict.items():
     if k1 == k2:
       print("Chicken Wing")
```

The chicken wing will never print because `type(k1) = <str>`
and `type(k2) = '<__main__.SomeObject'>`

How do I get around this? 
What exactly I am misunderstanding about OOP? 
What concepts should I read up on to help me understand?

All info is appreciated, thanks

Comment: "Now when I go to..." Please show the code that you describe here. And then explain what the result is and what you want it to do differently.

Comment: updated, please let me know if its unclear

Comment: There is no possible way that the keys in your dict could be lists - that would produce an "unhashable type" error.

Comment: Yes, the key in my dicts isn't of type `list`, Ideally I would want it to be a `str` - I guess if I rephrase this: How do I make `['Saturdays']` in the default dict key a `str`

Comment: So, in your question you should have said: `type(k1) = <str>`?

Comment: Yes, I just realised and updated :)

Comment: And another thing is that we can't see how `SomeObject.parsed_dates` is filled in. You have: `for test_set in SomeObject.parsed_dates:` and then on the next line: `test_set.accepts(dt)`. What object has an `accepts()` method?

Comment: My object? ....

Comment: What? `SomeObject`? You don't show it!

Comment: It doesn't do much... updated for you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207375/discussion-between-alex-and-quamrana).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it turns out that `test_set` is an instance of `SomeObject` which is why `type(k2) = '<__main__.SomeObject'>`.

It seems that the bit you are missing is:

```
d[str(test_set)].append(str(dt.isoformat()))
```

and then your `__repr__()` method will kick in.

**Update:**

The reason that `main()` returns `defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'Saturdays': ['2020-01-04', '2020-01-11', '2020-01-18']}` is that you have a `__repr__()` method and `defaultdict` is calling `str()` on each key of the dict.

Comment: Doesn't seem to help... all that happens is the key becomes `"['Saturdays']"`

Comment: So how do you call the constructor for SomeObject?